# How to give enter in a running shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I need some help for the my below shell script, i have master script where i can execute a exe file inside it, when this program is executed its prompting me  PRESS Any Key To Exit, after this i have few other commands to run.
As the exe file is not exiting the next commands are not getting executed and the main script is stuck.

so i need some help on how to give enter command in a running shell script and proceed without any break.

Comment: `echo | command`?

Comment: Where's your script? What source does this "exe file" read keys from? Stdin, the terminal, something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You did not add any code so it is not clear. However I can suggest your the below:

Suppose your exe is `my.exe` and you are executing it like below:-

```
./my.exe
```

Now modify that like below to run it on background which will fixed your issue. Just add the `&` at the end of the line.

```
 ./my.exe &
```